# Any example for Restlet TaskService?

Tags: java, restlet, taskservice

I am a Restlet program which will be executed in a Linux Server as a background process, since it is going to pull many data from several websites, I will make it to execute this task as a second thread for every 5 minutes; in Restlet I know there is a TaskService class which helps me to achieve this task; however I googled several results and also searched the stackoverflow posts but did not find any standalone example for using Restlet TaskService.

It is NOT common so that no one use this class compared with Activiti, Spring? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alison, this service implements the Java ScheduleExecutorService interface. More information on this service can be found in [regular Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and other Java tutorials.

Comment: The question was how to use Restlet TaskService with examples, not "where javadocs to ScheduleExecutorService can be found". Facing the similar problem, I can hardly find this helpful, since javadocs don't contain any good examples (as always).

Comment: Sorry that my answer doesn't fully solve your problem, but my point was to say that this issue isn't specific to the Restlet Framework but to the Java's concurrent interface ScheduleExecutorService. The RF web site recommends the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book to get documentation on these topics: http://restlet.org/learn/books